# Stack setup fails with package installation errors

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

I'm trying to get stack running for the first time, but running `stack setup` in an example project (from `stack new helloworld new-template`) fails with the following output (I skipped the beginning, which I think was normal):

```
Installing library in
/home/ajl/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-7.10.2/lib/ghc7.10.2/ghc_JzwEp1oQ8kA7NFNTGk1ho5 "/home/ajl/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-7.10.2/lib/ghc-7.10.2/bin/ghc-pkg" --force --global-package-db "/home/ajl/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-7.10.2/lib/ghc-7.10.2/package.conf.d" update rts/dist/package.conf.install
Reading package info from "rts/dist/package.conf.install" ... done.

: Warning: Unrecognized field 420 on line 420
(Skipped unrecognized field for every line 419 down to 1)
: Warning: Unrecognized field 1 on line 1
: missing id field
: invalid package identifier:
: invalid package key:
make[1]: *** [install_packages] Error 1
make: *** [install] Error 2

Installing GHC ...%
```

I'm on Ubuntu 14.04, running stack 1.0.2. Not sure if it's relevant but I have ghc 7.10.1 with Cabal 1.23.0.0 installed on the system already, which work fine.

I have tried changing the resolver to older LTS versions with older ghc versions. I also tried deleting `~/.stack`. Not sure what else to try given the unhelpfulness of the errors.

Comment: I just checked with your exact setup (well one difference: using it on Windows right now) and it works fine - I would interpret this as having problems with `rts/dist/package.conf.install` - can you check what's in there at line 420 and maybe edit your question to include the lines around this too?

Comment: Where would I find it? It's not in `~/.stack`, nor is it in the project directory.

Comment: it should be part of your base GHC installation

Comment: not 100% sure but you could try to remove the `ghc-options` from your `.cabal` (where the `-rtsopts` etc. are) and retry - maybe it'll stop trying to parse this file then (just to check)

Comment: Gave it a go, but it didn't help. I can't find any package.conf.install in my local ghc installation (did find in /usr to be sure). Half the reason I want to use stack is because it's self-contained anyway. Shouldn't it not be getting anything from my local machine?

Comment: well depends - for example it will use an local GHC (in your path) which is a good idea IMO

Comment: I've removed ghc from the system, reinstalled stack, delete ~/.stack ~/.ghc ~/.cabal and still the same error.

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out. The GHC build uses `grep` to make `packages.conf.install`. I have `GREP_OPTIONS=--color=auto -n` set in my zsh config. The `-n` was putting line numbers in front of everything, which was causing the errors.

The reason I couldn't find `packages.conf.install` anywhere before is because it is made on the fly during GHC `make`. And stack does that in /tmp.